# HTML 5 GeoLocation Accuracy

Tags: html, geolocation

I am using HTML 5 Geo Location Api
and use this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<script>
    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    function getLocation()
    {
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition,error,{ enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 150000, maximumAge: 0 });
        }
        else
        {
            x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }
    function showPosition(position)
    {
        x.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br />' +
            'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br />' +'Acc: ' + position.coords.accuracy     + '<br />'+
            '<hr />'      + x.innerHTML;
    }
    function error(err){alert(err);}
</script>
```

when i run above codein `Chrome` and `FireFox` it gives me accuracy value `122000` while in `IE` it gives 15 (which is more suitable)
So what i do to get more accurate result in chrome

Comment: If there isn't more accuracy, there isn't more accuracy. It's up to each individual browser to implement geolocation, some may do it better than others or some may work better than others in different situations.

Answer (score -1):

[W3C Geolocation API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-geolocation-API-20090707/) is currently supported in the major browsers.

- Internet Explorer (9.0+)
- Safari (5.0+)
- Firefox (3.5+)
- Opera (10.6+)
- Google Chrome (depends on OS)

Apparently you should use `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` to accomplish this in any supported browser.

How exactly accurate it is depends on browser vendor. You probably can get slight different results from each one.

Another alternative is [GeoLite service](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) from MaxMind, it is a free service and they update their database every first Tuesday of each month. You can retrieve this either binary or cvs formats.

For mobile browsers, you can take a look in [GPS Web Gate](http://code.google.com/p/mobile-gps-web-gate/), however most of all modern mobile browsers can support HTML5 GeoLocation as well.